# Debugging a wordpress for ipad mini

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, debugging

I recently found out that my WordPress website has lots of errors on iPad minis for some reasons. Including messed up design elements, slow loading, freezes and generally very low performance and responsiveness.

I'm not sure how can I debug it there, and see the errors/console.

Can someone advice? 
For reference website is sochi.asp.sale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your iPad Setting -> Safari -> Advanced -> Web Inspector.
[image]

And then, open Safari on your MacBook, see the develop of menu, you are going to find your device.

[image]

You can visit this link https://appletoolbox.com/2014/05/use-web-inspector-debug-mobile-safari/ to see more details.